# How do I link a Simulink block variable to a model constant?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simulink-library

I'm building a Simulink model for a dynamic simulation. Can I link a block's variable to a constant block? For example, as I am simulating the effect of sensor sampling frequency, I want to easily change the value associated with a ZeroOrderHold.

I know I can do it through a Matlab script and save the values to the Workspace, but the preferred way would be through a constant block in the Simulink model. In other words, I want my root Simulink model page to contain these constants, each associated with different blocks.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for the help

I tried using a goto block, but didn't work (see attached). I also tried a data memory store but again, no luck.

[Simulink screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqvu6.png)

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want unless the block has the option to set the values via an input port instead of the dialog box (for example the 1-D Lookup Table added this functionality within the last few years)